# Rails" Is it possible to know operation(update, create) being performed within validation method?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, customvalidator

Platform: Rail 3.0
Database: mysql 5.1

Business requirement: Only one item of a product can be issued at a time. After a return of the issued item, a new item can be issued of same product. Multiple items from different products can be issued at a time.

To implement the above business requirement, I am checking if there is already an item issued for the same product within the same date range (by checking to see if there is an overlap of the dates in my where below).

```
     class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
         validate :validate_one_item_for_product
         def validate_one_item_for_product
               items = Item.where( "issue_date < ? and return_date > ? and product_id = ?", return_date, issue_date, product_id)
               errors.add( :base, "item already issued for this product, not returned yet") if items.size > 0
         end
     end
```

Validation defined above works fine on create but in case of update i need to implement different logic. I do not want to define two methods for same requirement. so i want to implement checks with function based upon whether its update or create operation.Is there any way i can know if operation which triggered validate is update or delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validations can be run at any time, not just within `create`, `save`, `update_attributes`, etc. So even if you could know what method triggered the validation (you can hack around with the output of `caller`), you should not make any use of it because it could be something completely valid yet completely unexpected.

However, all is not lost. You can check whether the record has been persisted yet by calling `persisted?`.

```
 class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   validate :validate_one_item_for_product, :unless => :persisted?

 private

   def validate_one_item_for_product
     items = Item.where(
       "issue_date < ? and return_date > ? and product_id = ?",
       return_date, issue_date, product_id)
     if items.size > 0
       errors.add(:base,
         "item already issued for this product, not returned yet") 
     end
   end
 end
```

Comment: it seems like you are not in favor of using validate_on_create and validate_on_update instead of validate which can be used in my case instead of :unless => persisted. Here my concern is to overload function based upon update or create or to add checks in method defined based upon whether it is update or create call. So in that case solution provided by you will not work, right?

Comment: But somewhere i feel you telling me little sophisticated thing from your experince because i am facing one another problem also which may be related to what u suggested here, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400261/rails-methods-registered-on-validate-on-create-are-call-on-update-attributes-am

Comment: For one, do `validate :validate_method_for_create, :unless => :persisted?`; for the other, do `validate :valiate_method_for_update, :if => :persisted?`.

Comment: what abt sol, validate_on_create :validate_method_for_create for other validate_on_update :validate_method_for_update  this is what rails recommends in its tutorial what it not working as i specified in other question posted.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution is to define a method to validate it, with a parameter, and then have two validations with different `:on =>` calls, that in turn call the first method with a parameter.

Also, if it helps, you might use `new_record?` which will tell you if the object is being created (before it is saved)

Comment: Thanks. Can u please write few line syntax for :on => call ?